# Bluetooth Permission removal on JB4A on Android < 5.0

Tags: marketing-cloud, android, sfdcmobilesdk-android

In version 3 of the ExactTarget JB4A library that we use for push notifications, there was a dependency on the IBeacon library which imposed a requirement on the Bluetooth permission for the app. In the v4 update of the JB4A SDK, the documentation states no requirement on this library. Removing the library results in no problems for devices running Android 5 and above, but anything running Android 4.4.4 or below crashes on app launch without the library.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because - Contact App Vendor / Salesforce

Comment: @simon given most of this questions is out side of salesforce related domain knowledge I think you might have better luck getting some responses if you cross posted this on stackoverflow.com

Comment: @simon did, in fact, identify a bug in the JB4A Android SDK and it has been subsequently fixed.  This item should not have been voted closed.

Comment: @BillMote Is it safe to do the following for SDK 4.5.0 (if we don't want bluetooth in our app - is this the right way to do it and does the SDK correctly not crash if the lib is excluded):      

    compile ('com.exacttarget.etpushsdk:etsdk:4.5.0@aar') {
        exclude module: 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library'
    }

Comment: @jt-gilkeson Ask your question in a new question so I can provide a real answer.  Mention me here again, provide the link and I'll jump on it before these ^^^ clowns mark it as off topic.  Working on that issue separately ;)

Comment: @BillMote http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140914/how-can-we-remove-bluetooth-permissions-from-push-sdk-safely-for-sdk-15

Comment: @BillMote Please don't be too disparaging. We have reopened it.